# Export add-on error: rna_uiItemO: operator missing srna 'x.y'

Tags: export, add-on

I have a Blender add-on working well to perform an export. I try to upgrade it to Blender 2.80. I fixed some problems (https://github.com/petitg1987/UrchinEngine/commit/a07e6390caa4b231a8c463fc6bb5661cd4f0e6a7#diff-54ba6c537268c77d122862a62df64238) but now I'm stuck on this error:

```
rna_uiItemO: operator missing srna 'export.urchin'
/home/greg/.config/blender/2.80/scripts/addons/io_export_urchin.py:741
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/blender/scripts/modules/bpy_types.py", line 758, in draw_ls
    func(self, context)
  File "/home/greg/.config/blender/2.80/scripts/addons/io_export_urchin.py", line 741, in menuFunc
    self.layout.operator(ExportUrchin.bl_idname, text="Urchin Engine (.urchinMesh .urchinAnim)", icon='BLENDER').filepath = default_path
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'filepath'
```

Here is the source code:

```
class ExportUrchin(bpy.types.Operator):
  """Export Urchin Engine (.urchinMesh .urchinAnim)"""
  bl_idname = "export.urchin"
  bl_label = 'Export Urchin Engine'

  exportModes = [("mesh & anim", "Mesh & Anim", "Export mesh and anim"),
                 ("anim only", "Anim only", "Export anim only"),
                 ("mesh only", "Mesh only", "Export mesh only")]

  filepath: bpy.props.StringProperty(subtype='FILE_PATH', name="File Path", description="File path for exporting", maxlen=1024, default="")
  exportMode: bpy.props.EnumProperty(name="Exports", items=exportModes, description="Choose export mode", default='mesh only')
  meshScale: bpy.props.FloatProperty(name="Scale", description="Scale all objects from world origin (0,0,0)", min=0.001, max=1000.0, default=1.0, precision=6)

  def execute(self, context):
    global scale
    scale = self.meshScale
    settings = urchinSettings(savePath=self.properties.filepath, exportMode=self.properties.exportMode)
    saveUrchin(settings)
    return {'FINISHED'}

  def invoke(self, context, event):
    context.window_manager.fileselect_add(self)
    return {"RUNNING_MODAL"}

def menuFunc(self, context):
  default_path = os.path.splitext(bpy.data.filepath)[0]
  self.layout.operator(ExportUrchin.bl_idname, text="Urchin Engine (.urchinMesh .urchinAnim)", icon='BLENDER').filepath = default_path #Line 741
```

Full source code: https://github.com/petitg1987/UrchinEngine/blob/master/3dEngine/io_export_urchin.py

Could you please help me to understand the error ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The registration of the operator was broken. The [`bpy.utils.register_classes_factory()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.utils.html#bpy.utils.register_classes_factory) generates a `register()` and `unregister()` function for all supplied classes, but doesn't call them. There was also a `,` missing in the class tuple.

```
classes = (
    ExportUrchin,
)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.append(menuFunc)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    bpy.types.TOPBAR_MT_file_export.remove(menuFunc)
```